# CEF кросс-доменные запросы

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, cefsharp

Каким образом можно реализовать кросс-доменные запросы в CEF? Пробовал следующим образом, но результата не даёт - при создании запроса через `XMLHttpRequest`, он блокируется политикой. `AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry` возвращает true.

```
EventHandler<FrameLoadEndEventArgs> handler = null;
handler = delegate {
    WebBrowser.FrameLoadEnd -= handler;
    Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry("source.com", "HTTPS", "dist.com", false);
};
WebBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += handler;
```

Comment: Почитайте о том, как работает CORS. Ну а потом поищите, как этот CORS в хромиуме отключить. Вообще, запрещать или разрешать кросс-доменные запросы - ответственность сервера. Браузер всего-лишь подчиняется этому. Если сервер ваш, то проблему надо решать именно там.

Comment: _"как этот CORS в хромиуме отключить"_ - Есть вот такое решение: `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "disable-web-security");`. _"Если сервер ваш, то проблему надо решать именно там."_ - Сервер не мой.

Comment: @aepot У меня вопрос конкретно по `CefWebBrowser`. `AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry` должен работать.

Comment: @D.Stark может схемы не хватает у первого параметра? или апперкейс лишний - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54400318/1988244